# How do I combine two objects in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Consider:

```
public class test01{

    public void doSomething(){
        // do something
    }

}

public class test02{

    public void printSomething(){
        // print something
    }

} 

// in main
test01 t1 = new test01();
test02 t2 = new test02();

// I want do to something like this
test01 t3 = t1.merge(t2);

// with t3 I should be able to access both t1 and t2 functions
t3.doSomething();
t3.printSomething();
```

Please let me know if this is possible in Java? If yes, then let me know how can I achieve this?

Comment: It depends what you mean by _merge_.

Comment: What is object merging? :s

Comment: lookup interfaces, inheritance, oop, ...

Comment: For this task, you'll need interfaces and there you can declare both methdos

Comment: it may consists of dealing with bytecode of both classes. I mean you have to emulate Extends, interface operations using both classes. In addition You can use Adapter pattern.

Comment: What you're describing is multiple inheritance, which is not possible in Java (in most cases fortunately). Your options are to use interfaces and (starting with Java 8) default implementations of interface methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no multiple inheritance in java. What you can do is making `test02` a subclass of `test01` then create `test03` as a subclass of `test02`.

**OR**

you can compose them into a `Test03` class like this:

```
public class Test03 {

    private Test01 test01;
    private Test02 test02;

    public void doSomething() {
        test01.doSomething();
    }

    public void printSomething() {
        test02.printSomething();
    }

}
```

*Please note* that in java you shouldn't use class names like `test01`. They should be meaningful and comform to the java class naming guidelines.

Comment: I have tried this but here I have to rewrite all function defined in Test01 and Test02 in Test03. I have classes with 20 - 30 functions.

Comment: You don't have to rewrite them just delegate to them. If it is hard for you use the `extends` keyword for inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is probably this:

```
public class TestSet {
    private test01 t1 = new test01();
    private test02 t2 = new test02();

    public void doSomething() {
        t1.doSomething();
    }

    public void printSomething() {
        t2.printSomething();
    }
}
```

In some languages, multiple inheritance is supported, which may be what you're looking for here.  But not in Java.  You may or may not want to make a couple of interfaces here to tie TestSet more closely together with test01 and test02.

Answer (score 2):

> Please let me know if this is possible in Java?

It is not possible.  You cannot combine behaviour dynamically like that in Java.

The normal way to combine behaviour in Java is to use some combination of inheritance and wrappering or delegation.  Even then, there will be an issue of subtyping ... unless you use interfaces ... because Java does not allow a class to have multiple (direct) superclasses.

Consider for @Panzercrisis's example.  While his `test03` class implements methods with the same signatures as the `test01` and `test02` classes, an instance of `test03` is not type compatible with either of them.  (You can't use a `test03` instance as a `test01` or a `test02`.  Java doesn't support duck typing!)

To address that you would need to define interfaces `face01` and `face02` that are implemented by `test01` and `test02` respectively.  Then you would implement `test03` as implementing *both* `face01` and `face02`.

But this is all static classes and static typing.

---

Under some circumstances, you could use `DynamicProxy` or something similar to "synthesize" a class that "merges" the behaviour of two existing classes.  However,  that is all done with static types and code generation behind the scenes.  Moreover, this approach would only viable if you'd had the foresight to define a bunch of interfaces (e.g. `face01` and `face02`) and write your application code against the interfaces rather than the implementation classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class Y in another class X as inner class and you can use class Y in class X. Other than that, as I know there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no it's not possible how you describe.

The appearance of doing this might be possible if `test01` and `test02` where interfaces and you had a third class `test03` implement both.  In C++ this would be done by multiple inheritance but that would function much the same way (i.e. you would have to create a third class that instead extends both) and this option isn't available in Java anyway.

Another option would be some sort of composition such as @Panzercrisis describes.

The final option (I can think of) would be to have `test02` extend `test01` but that alters `test02`.

But generally, no, not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, really do this in way how you describe this,
you can do

> public class test01 extend test02{ ....
>
> }

so your test1, you can use methods from both classes,
but if you can really whant yo play with merging classes together, you can do some abomination like this one:

```
public class MyObject {
    Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Method> methods = new HashMap<String, Method>();

    public Object execute(String methodAName)
{

    Object object = objects.get(methodAName);
    Method method = methods.get(methodAName);
    if (object==null || method==null)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("method not found");
    }

    try {
        return method.invoke(object, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    }
}

    public void merge(Object o) {
        for (Method m : o.getClass().getMethods()) {
            objects.put(m.getName(), o);
            methods.put(m.getName(), m);
        }
    }
}
```

and when you can use it like that

```
 MyObject o = new MyObject();
 o.merge(new test01());
 o.merge(new test02());

 o.execute("printSomething");
 o.execute("doSomething");
```

but as i said, not recommended

Comment: This looks good but i'll rework on my design to use interface or inheritance. Thanks!

Comment: as i said, this code is abomination, interfaces is much better idea

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar using Java `inheritance`, But not the same thing. you can use `extends` here. But you have to make sure method overriding not happen else your requirement not match.

```
Test02 extends Test01
```

Then

```
Test03 extends Test02
```

Now you can achieve some thing similar.

```
Test03 test=new Test03();

test.callMethodInTest1();
test.callMethodInTest2();
```

Sample:

```
public class Test1 {

public String callMethodInTest1() {
    return "test1";
  }
}
```

.

```
public class Test2 extends Test1{

public String callMethodInTest2() {
    return "test2";
  }
}
```

.

```
public class Test03 extends Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args){
   Test03 sample=new Test03();
   sample.callMethodInTest1();
   sample.callMethodInTest2();
 }

}
```